# XPath matching the element with maximum value of an attribute

Tags: xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<users>

<user number="0775547857">
   <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
   <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
   <step stepnumber="3">complete</step>
</user>

<user number="0775543754">
   <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
   <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
</user>

<user number="0777743059">
   <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
</user>

</users>
```

Given a number, I want to find the maximum stepnumber in the list of steps.

What i've got so far is `//user[@number='0775547857']/step[@stepnumber]`

And i think I have to use the fn:max function but I am having trouble on how to use the max function passing the list of step numbers.

Example : If i give number `0775547857`, the maximum step number is `3` and for `0775543754` it is `2` and so on.

Thanx a lot in advance.

Is this correct?

```
//user[@number='0772243950']/step[fn:max((@stepnumber))]
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation and separate XPath 2.0 and XPath 1.0 solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max()` function is defined only in XPath 2.0 and above.

**An  XPath 2.0 expression that finds the maximum stepnumber** of the `step` children of a `user` that has a `number` attribute with value `$pNum` **is**:

```
max(/*/user[@number=$pNum]/step/@stepnumber/xs:integer(.))
```

Substituting `$pnum` with `0775547857` and evaluating this XPath 2.0 expression on the following XML document:

```
<users>
    <user number="0775547857">
        <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
        <step stepnumber="11">complete</step>
        <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
        <step stepnumber="3">complete</step>
    </user>
    <user number="0775543754">
        <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
        <step stepnumber="2">complete</step>
    </user>
    <user number="0777743059">
        <step stepnumber="1">complete</step>
    </user>
</users>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
11
```

**Do note**: using the `xs:integer(.)` above is necessary if we want to find the maximum of values as integers. Without it the maximum will be found on the values as strings and `3` will be bigger than `11`.

**In XPath 1.0 the following XPath expression returns the wanted maximum value**:

```
/*/user[@number=$pNum]/step
            [not(@stepnumber
                <
                 ../step/@stepnumber
                 )
            ]
              /@stepnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`fn:max(//user[@number='0775547857']/step[@stepnumber])`